# how to backup Joomla website when developing on MAMP?

Tags: web, joomla, backup, hosting, mamp

I am a new web developer. I have been using Joomla with a 3rd party template, developing it on a local MAMP server. The template is sort of unstable and breaks easily. I would like to Backup my work on a daily basis.

I'm assuming all the files and the database need to be backed-up? Is there a best practice for this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Easiest is to implement a simple script that first dumps the database into a file, then uses the `tar` utilty to create an archive.

Comment: Extra points for using `git` for version control ;-)

Comment: Really appreciate the tips. Do you know any of any resources that explains this further? Can't seem to find how to do it in layman terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Akeeba Backup (https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) is indeed a good idea. You can schedule a command line task to run every day and create a backup of this site. To restore such a backup you can use Akeeba Kickstart (https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html). Very easy, very comfortable.

But this only works if you don't break your Joomla! installation! Your question implies something like this. To do a manual backup you can simply zip the folder which contains your Joomla installation and create a database dump. You can do both every day using command line script.

Creating the dump: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

Using GIT might work as well. Instead of zipping your folder you simply commit it to your git repository. Don't forget to add the database dump to your repo as well.

https://techjoomla.com/developers-blogs/joomla-development/deploying-joomla-projects-using-git.html
http://joomlaablog.blogspot.de/2010/11/how-to-track-your-joomla-project-with.html

Answer (score 1):

The best and easy method is to get it done through Akeeba Backup https://www.akeebabackup.com/download.html. Install this component at the backend. Run it and take a backup whenever you want. It takes backup of files and database both. You can even download and extract it to run it in another web server. To extract Akeeba you can use their software [Akeeba Extract](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-extract-wizard.html). This is all free.